# How to convert String to int array?

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android Studio and I have this String in one of my activities:

```
[0, 25, 24, 25, 15, 16, 17, 25, 24, 21, 24]
```

and I want to convert it to a int[] :

```
{0, 25, 24, 25, 15, 16, 17, 25, 24, 21, 24};
```

How do I do that? 
I tried the code below, but it's not returning the correct value.

```
int[] intArray = new int[string.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    intArray[i] = Character.digit(string.charAt(i), 10);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called "parsing". You will need to solve this with your own code. There is no built-in method in Java or Android to do so. You should look at the methods available in the `String` class, especially `matches()` and `split()`.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, you can make use of `org.json.JSONArray`:

```java
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(arr); // throws JSONException
int length = jsonArray.length();
int[] results = new int[length];

for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  results[i] = jsonArray.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] arr = [...];
int[] ints = new int[arr.length()];
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length() ; i++){
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
}
```